# How to use xml key and values in xaml binding

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LanguageDictionary>
  <item key="ButtonBackground" value="Red"/>
</LanguageDictionary>
```

**XAML**

```
  <ResourceDictionary>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="brushes" Source="LayoutConfiguration.xml" XPath="/LanguageDictionary/item"/>
  </ResourceDictionary>

 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WhiteBrush" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource brushes}, XPath=ButtonBackground}" />
```

I have code like above. But it is not working. Is it possible to change the brush color from xml using its key value.

Answer (score 2):

<del>The value you bind to is a string, not a color. So you have to create a converter (inherited from `IValueConverter`) to convert from string to Color:</del>

```
public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var color = System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString((string)value);
        return color;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value?.ToString();
    }
}
```

<del>Then you can use this converter in your binding:</del>

---

**EDIT after comments:**
The XPath really seems to be invalid. Please, find below the sample that actually works:

```
<Window x:Class="TestXmlBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestXmlBinding"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider Source="LayoutConfiguration.xml" XPath="/LanguageDictionary" x:Key="brushes" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="br" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource brushes}, XPath=item\[@key\=\'ButtonBackground\']/@value}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource br}" Text="Test" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Please, note that you have to escape some XPath characters inside Binding markup extension.

Additionally, the Color seems to have the associated TypeConverter, so you do not need the IValueConverter for the Color type.

Comment: I have added a converter. Still the brush color is not changed

Comment: Probably your XPath is also incorrect. I do not remember the syntax, but it should be something like [@key='ButtonBackground']/@value

Comment: By the way, you can put the breakpoint into the converter and check whether it is ever called and what data it receives. If it is never called, your XPath is likely incorrect.

Comment: Thanks. Without StringToColorConverter. background is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Yes similar to Pavel code, even i tried it and its taking the color from xml file which you have added above.

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<LanguageDictionary>
  <item key="ButtonBackground" value="red"/>
</LanguageDictionary>
```

Resource file

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <XmlDataProvider Source="LayoutConfiguration.xml" XPath="/LanguageDictionary" x:Key="brushes" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="xmlColorKey" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource brushes}, XPath=item\[@key\=\'ButtonBackground\']/@value}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

xaml

```
 <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock  FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" Background="{StaticResource xmlColorKey}" Text="Color Test" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

It is taking new color once application is build.